# How can I actually adjust the brightness of my display?

Tags: lenovo, laptop, brightness

I'm on a fresh installation of Ubuntu and planning to install i3wm. Unfortunately, the brightness is completely stuck on the maximum, rendering it basically torture to use during the night. Neither the brightness keys on my keyboard nor the brightness slider on the top right dropdown do anything. The brightness keys do show that the brightness is decreasing on the slider but it doesn't actually change at all. Please help! I'm using a Lenovo Flex 5 14.

Edit: It's definitely not the laptop itself's problem because the brightness buttons worked when I was on Windows and when I shut down the computer, the space around the Shut Down prompt is darker.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing it with `xrandr`

```
xrandr --output <display> --brightness <value between 0 and 1>
```

If you are unsure about the display name just press tab once you get to it.

For example I would use:

```
xrandr --output eDP-1-1 --brightness .5
```

You can try to use `xbacklight`

Or you could try the application `brightness-controller` .
See the [Github page](https://github.com/apandada1/Brightness) or install with

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:apandada1/brightness-controller
sudo apt update
sudo apt install brightness-controller
```

Comment: When using `xrandr --output` and then tabbing it gives me Failed to get size of gamma for output default

Comment: try `xrandr -q | grep " connected"` . You shoud get a list with the first entry beeing display name.

Comment: Here's the output: `xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
default connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 0mm x 0mm`

Comment: hm. have you tried to not give any display and just `xrandr --output --brightness <value between 0 and 1>`.

Comment: Doesn't work. `xrandr: unrecognized option '0.4'`

Comment: the same happens for me without a display chosen. so you could either try something like `primary` or `default`. Other than that you might want to try to use `xbacklight` or `brightness-controller`.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it! Turns out this is an issue with my laptop's APU, the 4500u. I had to update the kernel to 5.8 and then boot without Secure Boot in the BIOS.